# Css works for the first radio set, but not the second radio set

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make a quiz app with many questions and Yes or No  answers.

So I made a design to make a radio button look like a button and for it to be checked if selected.

I also used javascript to make a slider for that questions.

So the problem is the checked design worked with the first question in the slider but would not work for the rest of the questions.

Here is my code, I don't think that the error in JS but I included it anyways.

```js
const myslide = document.querySelectorAll('.myslide'),
      dot = document.querySelectorAll('.dot');
let counter = 1;
slidefun(counter);

let timer = setInterval(autoSlide, 8000);

function plusSlides(n) {
    counter += n;
    slidefun(counter);
    resetTimer();
}
function currentSlide(n) {
    counter = n;
    slidefun(counter);
    resetTimer();
}
function resetTimer() {
    clearInterval(timer);
    timer = setInterval(autoSlide, 8000);
}

function slidefun(n) {
    
    let i;
    for(i = 0;i<myslide.length;i++){
        myslide[i].style.display = "none";
    }
    for(i = 0;i<dot.length;i++) {
        dot[i].className = dot[i].className.replace(' active', '');
    }
    if(n > myslide.length){
       counter = 1;
       }
    if(n < 1){
       counter = myslide.length;
       }
    myslide[counter - 1].style.display = "block";
    dot[counter - 1].className += " active";
}
```

```css
.txt input[type="radio"] {
    opacity:0.011;
    z-index:100;
    
}

.txt label {
    padding:5px;
    
    border:1px solid #000;
    border-radius:10px; 
    cursor:pointer;
    
   
}
.txt label:hover {
    background: rgb(238, 255, 5);
}


input[type="radio"]:checked + label {
    background:yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="myslide fade">
    <div class="txt">

        <p>What is the question two ?</p>

        <input id="yes" type='radio' name="result" value="yes">
        <label for="yes">Yes</label>
        <br> 
        <input id="no" type='radio' name="result" value="no">
        <label for="no">No</label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <img src="{% static 'img/img1.jpg'%}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>

<div class="myslide fade">
    <div class="txt">
        <p>What is the question one ?</p>
        <input id="yes" type='radio' name="Question1" value="yes">
        <label for="yes">Yes</label>
        <br> 
        <input id="no" type='radio' name="Question1" value="no">
        <label for="no">No</label>
        <br>
    </div>
    <img src="{% static 'img/img1.jpg'%}" style="width: 100%; height: 100%;">
</div>
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Right now it gives a js error because there is not `dots` class name anywhere. Is there more code that you left out?

Comment: @Sensoray Yeah this class is for the number of questions,I  left that out I just include the radio button section.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that your radio inputs can't have the same ids and have the labels target those same ids. Ids are supposed to be a unique occurrence in the DOM, and the labels are also supposed to reference those unique occurrences. So you need to change the `id` of the inputs and the `for` of the labels to correlate to each other specifically.

For example, changing them to "yes1 & no1, and yes2 & no2". This should solve your issue:

```
<p>What is the question one ?</p>

<input id="yes1" type='radio' name="Question1" value="yes">
<label for="yes1">Yes</label>
<br> 
<input id="no1" type='radio' name="Question1" value="no">
<label for="no1">No</label>
```

and

```
<p>What is the question two ?</p>

<input id="yes2" type='radio' name="result" value="yes">
<label for="yes2">Yes</label>
<br> 
<input id="no2" type='radio' name="result" value="no">
<label for="no2">No</label>
```